# if-statement with negative condition

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to make the following if-statement

```
if (!(zfs list -t snapshot -o name -H | grep -q secure) && (echo $days | grep -q $day) )
```

so when the first command doesn't return anything and the second return `true`, it should be executed.

If I try

```
if ! zfs list -t snapshot -o name -H | grep -q secure && echo $days | grep -q $day; then
  echo ok
fi
```

then I can't not make it fail. It always prints `ok`.

**Question**

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way how I was able to make it output `ok` was zfs reporting `secure` and `$days` containing `$day`. Any other combination (i.e. zfs not reporting `secure` or $days`not containing`$day`) produced no output.

As I do not have `zfs`, I defined a function:

```
function zfs () { echo secure ; } ; days=1; day=1; if ! zfs list -t snapshot -o name -H | grep -q secure && echo $days | grep -q "$day" ; then echo ok; fi
function zfs () { echo securX ; } ; days=1; day=1; if ! zfs list -t snapshot -o name -H | grep -q secure && echo $days | grep -q "$day" ; then echo ok; fi
function zfs () { echo securX ; } ; days=0; day=1; if ! zfs list -t snapshot -o name -H | grep -q secure && echo $days | grep -q "$day" ; then echo ok; fi
function zfs () { echo secure ; } ; days=0; day=1;if  ! zfs list -t snapshot -o name -H | grep -q secure && echo $days | grep -q "$day" ; then echo ok; fi

function zfs () { echo secure ; } ;  days=0; day=1; if ( ! ( zfs list -t snapshot -o name -H | grep -q secure) && (echo $days | grep -q "$day" ) ); then echo ok; fi
function zfs () { echo securX ; } ;  days=0; day=1; if ( ! ( zfs list -t snapshot -o name -H | grep -q secure) && (echo $days | grep -q "$day" ) ); then echo ok; fi
function zfs () { echo securX ; } ;  days=1; day=1; if ( ! ( zfs list -t snapshot -o name -H | grep -q secure) && (echo $days | grep -q "$day" ) ); then echo ok; fi
function zfs () { echo secure ; } ;  days=1; day=1; if ( ! ( zfs list -t snapshot -o name -H | grep -q secure) && (echo $days | grep -q "$day" ) ); then echo ok; fi
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a workaround rather than an answer, but you could reverse the sense of the test with `grep` itself using `-v`:

```
if zfs list -t snapshot -o name -H | grep -qv secure && echo $days | grep -q $day; then
  echo ok
fi
```

although this is not quite the same in the case where `zfs list -t snapshot -o name -H` returns nothing at all.